# Scrollbars do not show on iPad

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane, jquery-jscrollpane

I am Using jQuery 1.8.1 amd jScrollPane v2.0.0beta12. The scrollbars look fine on a desktop browser, but they do not get included on the iPad at all. By inspecting the DOM (using Adobe Shadow), I can see, that the div elements of these sliders do not exist. Did anybody encountered a similar issue and solved it? I appreciate any help in this issue.

Comment: I think I've encountered this problem before. I had to revert to an older jQuery version if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 0):

just a hunch, but try adding this to your head and see if it helps:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: It doesn't really change anything

Answer (score 0):

By default, scroll bars don't show on mobile browsers. You need a widget that is specially made to show your own scroll bars for mobile browsers. Note that you can still scroll using a two finger swipe.

See http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/

Comment: jScrollPane is supposed to do this. I just tested their demo site [link](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/basic.html). There it works on the iPad. They use an older jQuery version, though.